# Get Extra map from Urban Airship notification

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

In a service I'm creating, the server sends push notifications to the clients (which are Android apps). I'm using Urban Airship. In addition to the alert text, I'm also sending extra information as [shown here](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60532-sending-custom-push-data)

In the app, I want to access this extra information. Unfortunately, all I could find was [`EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA`](http://docs.urbanairship.com/android-lib/reference/com/urbanairship/push/PushManager.html#EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA) property I can get from the Intent. The documentation explains that `STRING_EXTRA` has been deprecated, and instead I can access a `Map`.

I just couldn't figure out *how* to access the extra map. Where can I find it?